# how to return value from service result handler in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I going to call only "clickfun()" method i need urlPath value after success service return value. but it throws stack overflow errors. Any help please.

```
private function clickfun(eve:Event):String{
            languagecode = "assets/myFont_en.swf";
            Defaultlanguagecode = "assets/myFont_default.swf";
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(languagecode);
            var xmlURLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);
            xmlURLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadcompletefun);
            xmlURLLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,ioerrorFun);
            xmlURLLoader.load(request); 
            return getpath();

        }

        private function getpath():String{
            if(loadcomplete == true){
                Alert.show(urlpath);
                return urlpath;
            }else
                return getpath(); 


        }
        private function loadcompletefun(e:Event):void{
            loadcomplete = true;
            urlpath = languagecode;
        }
        private function ioerrorFun(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
            loadcomplete = true;
            urlpath = Defaultlanguagecode;
        }



<mx:Panel title="Embedded Fonts Using ActionScript" width="800" height="500">
            <mx:Button label="Click" id="btn" click="clickfun(event)"/>
</mx:Panel>
```

Comment: It's hard to debug such things without knowing what the error is.  Please edit your question to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious with your remote interaction code is that loaders load data asynchronously. This means that the execution of the program continues while the loaders load data on a (virtually) different thread.

The issue is here you call `getpath()` right after you have started the load. This makes `loadcomplete` false, and the getpath function keeps recursing and the stack overflows.

What you SHOULD so is:

Let your class dispatch an event. Say you dispatch just a `Event.COMPLETE` event.

Tell it to the IDE like this:

Near your class declaration, add the metadata and make your class extend EventDispatcher

```
//Imports and package declaration

[Event(name="complete", type="flash.events.Event")]
public class YourClassName extends EventDispatcher {

    //Remaining part of class here
```

Then, in your `loadcompletefun`, add this

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
```

And, in the place you call `clickfun`, do this:

```
o=new YourClassName();
o.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gp);
```

and, declare `gp` as

```
private function gp(e:Event):void {
    trace(getpath());
    //You now have the ability to call getpath()
}
```

Comment: @RajaJaganathan: accept the answer. Also accept answers to your previous questions. In addition to giving you reputation, it shows up on your profile and people are more motivated to answer your future questions then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a review of the code, I'm guessing you are receiving an error because the loadcomplete and urlpath variables are not defined. so, make sure you define it in your ActionScript block:

```
public var loadcomplete : Boolean
public var urlPath : String
```

Also make sure that you define languagecode and Defaultlanguagecode as variables using the same approach.

Any one of these omissions could cause a compile time or runtime error.

Comment: hey, your assessment is wrong. He gets the error because he hasn't understood the asynchronous-ness of loaders in AS3

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Without knowing the error he is getting neither of us can be sure of the solution.